# How to make auto login in shopify site?

Tags: shopify

I have my main site in React.js and I have also had a Shopify store in the subdomain. I want when a user sign-in in the main site and when he redirected to Shopify site will log in here also with the same account. and vice versa.

How we can share or pass the same login in Shopify site or from Shopify site to another site.

Is there any API or function for this.

Please suggest me on this with your useful thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an option for the Shopify Plus users. If you already have some application and wants to allow your users to access Shopify without logging in again you can use Multipass. According to Shopify website

> Multipass login is for store owners who have a separate website and a
>   Shopify store. It redirects users from the website to the Shopify
>   store and seamlessly logs them in with the same email address they
>   used to sign up for the original website. If no account with that
>   email address exists yet, one is created. There is no need to
>   synchronize any customer databases.

[Shopify Multipass Details](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/multipass)

If a user directly visit Shopify store on sub-domain and want to login, redirect him to your main site login (React app) and redirect back after successful login via Multipass URL.